# Unable to unzip zip file created by zip4j library java

Tags: java, zip, jakarta-mail, zip4j

I am using Zip4j to convert some string data into a password protected zip file. Next I send this zip file as an attachment via email.
Issue is that sometimes (failure rate like 4%, rest 96% of the time it works) I am unable to unzip (using unzip command on mac) the file that I receive in the email, the error received while unzipping the file is as below:

```
 7 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  7
  (attempting to re-compensate)

error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
```

It seems the contents of the body that are in the zip file does not matter, for example: zipping and sending the email the first time  does not work but doing this agin with same contents works. I am unable to reproduce this locally.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new 
    ByteArrayOutputStream();
    net.lingala.zip4j.io.ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new 
    net.lingala.zip4j.io.ZipOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

    ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
    parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
  parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
    parameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
    parameters.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_STANDARD);
    parameters.setPassword("zipFilePassword");
    parameters.setFileNameInZip(subject + ".txt");
    parameters.setSourceExternalStream(true);
    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(null, parameters);

    zipOutputStream.write("some regular text".getBytes());
    zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
    zipOutputStream.finish();

    DataSource attachment = new 
    ByteArrayDataSource(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), 
    "text/plain");
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(attachment));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(subject + ".zip");

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    ........
```

**Some changes that I do plan to make is:**

1. Set mime type to application/zip instead of text/plain when creating an instance of ByteArrayDataSource.
2. May be not use compression at all since the data that I am sending is very small, so use parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_STORE);

Looked at this topic http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/forum/index.php?topic=434.msg1297#msg1297 , but that is applicable for AES encryption and here I am using the ENC_METHOD_STANDARD so I assume this does not apply.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Definitely change the MIME type to application/zip.  It’s possible that is the source of your problem, as a MIME message may encode text in various ways, but will not alter binary data.

Comment: @VGR thanks for the input. But would that also explain why for the same exact input (but different password) it does not work the first time but tying again works.